# Calculating Pixel Distance in QT C++

Tags: c#, c++

I am writing an  application , to  compare  2 images of same dimensions  ,  I need to compare distance For example if two images of the Same then the distance between those two images would be zero. If two images are completely different than the distance between them would be quite large.The project involves taking a sample image and using that as a base and seeing any distortions in color or  gradient have occurred in the subsequent images.

Comment: What is your question? And what have you tried?

Comment: So far nothing , I was  looking OpenCV ,  or some other image processing library

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to define a distance between images which is similar to what the human brain recognizes as "close" images. In particular distortion of images is not easy to catch. However if you only look at pointwise distortion of color and gradients you can define a distance between images A and B as:

```
d(A,B) = sqrt ( sum ( A(i,j)-B(i,j) )^2 )
```

where A(i,j) is the 3D-vector with RGB components of the color of pixel at coordinates i,j in image A.

Comment: I was thinking more in the lines of Damerau–Levenshtein distance  ,  I know is is applied  to  string or  array of  characters , I was kind of hoping I could get some thing  similar for images.